# How to call javascript function from dropdownlist?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have javscript function which I want to call from dropdownlist.If I call javascript function from onchange event of dropdownlist from page_load,my dropdownlist's selectedIndexchanged event does not fire.How to handle it?.I want to call both javascript function and selectedindexchanged from dropdownlist.

```
//Javascript
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
          function()
          {
          }
          </script>

//Page_load()
    ddlSubject.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return CallSubject()");
```

//

```
protected void ddlSubject_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Suppose I have button control and want call javascript function from button.I will call javascript function from button's onclientclick event,after that my button's click event fire.I want like that in dropdownlist.

Comment: why dont you call the server side `ddlSubject_SelectedIndexChanged` event first and then after this is done, make a call to javascript function from server side.

Comment: No I don't want like this....

Comment: try the input- event

Comment: @Test sorry I did not get u...

Comment: Can you try this `$('select').on('change',function(){  alert('changed!!'); })`

Comment: @Reddy I am new to jQuery.....

Comment: @JuiTest this is called event binding . So the code above binds a change event to your select tag. select tag is the dropdown element.